# "Content is not allowed in prolog" Error validation DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

I have a problem with the validation of XML file with a DTD. I read about it but i cant found a solution. I have this XML file:

﻿

```
<!DOCTYPE compra SYSTEM "compras.dtd">
<compra>
  <comprador nif="12345678X">
    <nombre>Pepito</nombre>
    <apellidos>Palotes</apellidos>
  </comprador>
  <fecha>
    <dia>15</dia>
    <mes>octubre</mes>
    <year>2017</year>
  </fecha>
  <linea_de_pedido>
    <articulo id="1">
      <nombre>zapatillas</nombre>
      <categoria>deporte</categoria>
      <stock>1000</stock>
    </articulo>
    <descripcion>Las mejores zapatillas para salir a correr</descripcion>
    <cantidad>1</cantidad>
    <precio moneda="euro">75.20</precio>
  </linea_de_pedido>
  <precio_total>75.20</precio_total>
</compra>
```

I have this DTD for the validation:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!ELEMENT compra (comprador|fecha|linea_de_pedido|precio_total)*>

<!ELEMENT comprador (nombre|apellidos)*>
<!ATTLIST comprador
    nif CDATA #IMPLIED
  >

<!ELEMENT nombre (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT apellidos (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT fecha (dia|mes|year)*>

<!ELEMENT dia (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT mes (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT linea_de_pedido (articulo|descripcion|cantidad|precio)*>

<!ELEMENT articulo (nombre|categoria|stock)*>
<!ATTLIST articulo
    id CDATA #IMPLIED
  >

<!ELEMENT categoria (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT stock (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT descripcion (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT cantidad (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT precio (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST precio
    moneda CDATA #IMPLIED
  >

<!ELEMENT precio_total (#PCDATA)>
```

And this is the error in the validation process:

```
XML validation started.
Checking file:/C:/Java/texto/src/compras.xml...
El contenido no está permitido en el prólogo. [1] 
XML validation finished.
```

> "Content is not allowed in prolog. [1]" in English.

Where is the problem??

Comment: You're missing the prolog in your XML, i.e the bit that looks something this: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`

Comment: Didn't appear to be that. Im doing the validation in other documents without this. Whatever, if i put this line (the same prolog as the DTD) this still not working.

Comment: Unable to replicate; both xmllint and rxp accept this XML input as valid against this DTD.  What validator are you using?  Have you tried commenting out the XML declaration at the beginning of the DTD?

Comment: I was using NetBeans, Whatever, I fixed the problem by deleting the first tag and typing again. Netbeans should be detecting it badly.

Comment: Ah.  Sounds as if you may have had an invisible Unicode character at the beginning of your file, which you were able to delete.

Comment: Works in .Net and Xerces. I would guess its objecting to the <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> in the DTD though. This is not normally added to DTD's